# help identifying silcock parts

Tags: plumbing, valve

I have a broken silcock with no identifying marks on the valve body.
Here is a picture of the internals, with the boot w/ sealing surface separated from the rod that pushes it against the valve seat:
[image: picture of silcock rod and valve boot]

I'm having no luck finding a replacement. Any help identifying would be much appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: …and for those who have never heard of a silcock - it's a hose bib - https://www.1tomplumber.com/what-is-a-sillcock/

Comment: And it should be noted that the pictured sillcock is a "frost-proof" one.

Comment: If you can't get matching parts by going to a plumbing supply and showing them what you have, you get a whole new sillcock.

Comment: I'd suggest that simply replacing the entire sillcock is going to be faster, easier, and quite possibly cheaper.

Comment: I've replaced two others with new silcocks already and I've already spoken to people at supply stores. This post is a last ditch to not have to deal with one that's a bigger pain to get at than the others!

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's just a simple washer or packing material that needs replacement, finding replacement parts will not be easy. By the time these start to fail, the new ones have completely changed so parts are not interchangeable. You could try an old fashion hardware store, like the ones we had before Home Depot and Lowe's, or a plumbing supply store. If you can't find parts, you'll have to replace the whole thing. It's usually a pretty easy job if you can get to the inside wall where the silcock attaches to the pipe. I've replaced many in the midwest because replacement parts were just non existent.

Comment: You are correct that it's hard to find parts, as I've already failed to find them by doing the usual thing! 
This one is the least accessible and worth a few more hours of searching for parts.

Comment: Note that local hardware stores sometimes have learned what components were used in houses built in their neighborhoods, and may stock (or at least recognize) parts that a big-box or website won't.